# Are composite fields unique?

Tags: field-theory

Suppose for $i=1,2$ that $\Omega_i$ is a field containing fields $K_i$ and $L_i$, with $K_1 \cong K_2$ and $L_1 \cong L_2$.
Is it then true that there is an isomorphism $K_1L_1 \cong K_2L_2$ of composite fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider e.g. non-Galois situations, like

- $\Omega_1={\bf C} \quad K_1={\bf Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \quad L_1={\bf Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$
- $\Omega_2={\bf C} \quad K_2={\bf Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \quad L_2={\bf Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})$

where $\omega$ is a nonreal $3$rd root of unity.